# Like buttons showing different values for same link

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Got a problem that has been bugging me for a few days now

On the following page:

```
notable.ca/stoli/CASIESTEWART/
```

for the first image the FB like button shows '9' (at the time of this post)

On this page for the same url

```
notable.ca/stoli/casiestewart/254/
```

the like button shows '2' (at the time of this post)

When i query using the facebook tool it also shows '2' (at the time of this post)

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+url%2C+normalized_url%2C+share_count%2C+like_count%2C+comment_count%2C+total_count%2C+commentsbox_count%2C+comments_fbid%2C+click_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url%3D%22notable.ca/stoli/casiestewart/254/%22
```

Does anyone know how two facebook buttons can be showing different numbers for the same URL?

Comment: This article may give you insight to the problem. http://faso.com/fineartviews/21028/facebook-like-button-count-inaccuracies

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how two facebook buttons can be showing different numbers for the same url?

Because the do **not** point to the *same URL*, but two **different** ones!

The URLs for the like button iframes on the first page you mentioned are all wrong, they all look something like this,

`<iframe src='http://facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fnotable.ca%2Fstoli%2Fcasiestewart%2F254%2F"&amp;send=false&amp;…`

– notice the `"` at the end of the `href`parameter, before `&amp;send=false`.

So you have *actually* been liking the URL [http://notable.ca/stoli/casiestewart/254/"](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=http://notable.ca/stoli/casiestewart/254/%22) all the time (click on this link, it shows you that it has 9 shares right now in the Graph API explorer), whereas you probably *wanted* to like [http://notable.ca/stoli/casiestewart/254/](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=http://notable.ca/stoli/casiestewart/254/) instead, which has 4 shares by now.

Mystery solved.